# I can't access my computer through specific port

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, fedora, linux-networking

On Fedora 18 I tried to access port 1521, so I opened the following port on my firewall:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
```

and

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
```

and

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
```

I then tried to telnet to my inner IP (the IP that the router gave me) and got connection refused:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.103 1521
Trying 192.168.1.103...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.103: Connection refused
```

I then tried to telnet to my internet IP and didn't get any response:

```
$ telnet x.x.x.x 1521
Trying x.x.x.x...
```

As far as I can tell, I've opened my port on the router also, BTW, I also tried it with port 22 and got the same result.

There is oracle listener up that listen to the port 1521, so beside `telnet` i've tried also `tnsping` and `sqlplus`. but the connection get timeout so its a firewall issue for now.

Comment: How did you get an interface named `eth0`?

Answer (score 0):

You're allowing traffic in `eth0` but then testing from the localhost? The traffic is NOT passing through `eth0`, it will be seen in the `lo` interface instead. Update your rule to either remove `-i eth0`, or change `eth0` to `lo`, or add a second rule for `lo`.

After that, confirm that Oracle is definitely listening on that port using `netstat -tnlp | grep 1521`

Next, confirm that `eth0` is the correct interface to be allowing the traffic with `ip a s`. IIRC, Fedora uses the "new" method of naming interfaces these days, so it may be something like `enp3s0` instead.

As a side note, you don't need to run the save command after running iptables commands, they are live as soon as you run the command. The save command saves the rules for the next reboot (or reload)

Comment: I dropped the `-i` argument from the first command and run it. now telnet to the 192.168.1.103 ip with port 1521 get connected, however it does not to the internet ip, and also the tnsping get timed out. `netstat` return a line. and `ip a s` return `lo` with 127.0.0.1 ip and `p20p1` with 192.168.1.103 ip.

Comment: So you need to use `p20p1` instead of `eth0` as the argument to `-i`. You are unlikely to get it to work by connecting to the router from the local machine (most routers won't "bounce route" port forwards). Use an external machine to test the port-forwarding of your router.

Comment: doesnt work from remote computer. and I dont understand why its ok that I cant access my internet ip. anyway as i said inner ip(local and router) works. internet does not.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for that since your iptables is working and debugging a separate issue in the comments is messy.